# Solving equation containing different terms of the form x^x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

Is it possible to solve the following equation for $x$ as a function of $y$:
$$\sqrt{\frac{x+k}{x}}\,\frac{(x+k)^{x+k}}{x^x}=y$$
in a way that the resulting equation $x=f(y)$ is something I can evaluate easily on a computer? Preferably just using standard operations, i.e. without any long iterative or otherwise "expensive" operations.

**Update**:

Let me add a plot for a couple values of $k$:

[image: Plot]

Comment: As a heuristic, try plotting with WolframAlpha to see if it's injective for some values of k. If it's not, then you have your answer :P

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun I added a plot for a couple of k-values and it does look injective. ;) (at least in my region of interest: $x\,\ge\,1$)

Comment: I do not think that explicit solutions of $x(y)$ could be obtained. So, probably, numerical methods will need to be used ... but you don't want that. By the way, they will not be expensive using Newton as the simplest root-finder.

Comment: Do you considered Lambert's W (Omega) function? If you let me use this function I can try to manipulate that equation to get closed form solutions, if no then my answer is: you can't solve that equation with standard operations (at least not in a closed form but only with numerical approximations).

Comment: @RenatoFaraone Looks like there are some approximations for evaluating the Lambert's W function and some iterative solutions that might converge quickly enough. But, either way I would love to see how to solve the equation in this way, since I've never worked with the W function and it never hurts to learn something new! Could you include the crucial steps in your answer so I can follow the derivation? That would be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: As far as I can tell, Lambert W does not help in solving this one

Comment: @MarkusA. Challenge accepted! :)

Comment: @RenatoFaraone Awesome! That's the spirit! ;) You're up against 157K+ rep (I'm assuming you meant Robert Isreal's comment as the challenge), but I'm definitely rooting for **you**! :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as Ross Millikan answered, consider the function $$F(x)=(x+k+\frac 12)\log (x+k) - (x+\frac 12) \log (x ) - \log (y)$$ which is much better conditioned than the original one (and basically the plots you gave justify this choice). What is nice is that $$F'(x)=\log \Big(\frac{x+k} x\Big)-\frac{k}{2 x (k+x)}$$ $$F''(x)=\frac{k^2+2k\left(1- k\right) x-2 k x^2}{2 x^2 (k+x)^2} $$ which make calculations quite simple.

You can notice that $$F(1)=\left(k+\frac{3}{2}\right) \log (k+1)-\log (y)$$ $$F''(1)=-\frac{k^2}{2 (k+1)^2}$$ So, the second derivative being negative, starting iterations at $x_0=1$, Newton will converge without any overshoot of the solution if $F(1)<0$ that is to say if $y >(k+1)^{k+\frac{3}{2}}$.

For illustration purposes, let us choose $k=5$ and $y=10^6$. Let us start iterating from $x_0=1$. The successive iterates of Newton method will be : $2.57740$, $2.96780$, $2.98335$, $2.98337$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Let us do the same for $k=4$ and $y=10^6$. Starting again with $x_0=1$, the successive iterates are $5.10406$, $8.34810$, $9.14836$, $9.17912$, $9.17916$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Reworking the general form, starting iterating at $x_0=1$, the first iterate of Newton method is given by $$x_1=1+\frac{2 \log (y)-(k+1) ((2 k+3) \log (k+1))}{2 (k+1) \log (k+1)-k}$$ which  you could use as a starting point $x_0$ if you want to save one iteration (but this is really not necessary).

Repeating the same exercises using Halley method, the iterates for the first case would be $2.89155$, $2.98337$; for the second case : $7.33230$, $9.17026$, $9.17916$. This seems to be quite faster.

Please remember that you can automate these calculations using the most basic version of Excel.

**Edit**

Suppose that you solved the equation for given values $k_1,y$ and obtained the solution $x_1$. Now, you want to approximate the solution for $k_2,y$. Using implicit differentiation, you will get $$\frac{dx}{dk}=\frac{2 (k+x) \log (k+x)+2 k+2 x+1}{2 x (k+x) (\log (x)-\log (k+x))+k}\,x$$ that is to say  $$x_2\approx x_1\Big(\frac{2 (k_1+x_1) \log (k_1+x_1)+2 k_1+2 x_1+1}{2 x_1 (k_1+x_1) (\log (x_1)-\log (k_1+x_1))+k_1}\,(k_2-k_1)\Big) $$ Try with the examples : starting with $k_1=5$, this would give $\frac{dx}{dk}=-3.57084 $; so, for $k_2=5.1$, $x_2 \approx 2.62629$ while the exact solution would be $2.64148$.

**Edit**

Admitting that the problem needs to be solved for values such that $0\leq x\leq 10$ and $1\leq k\leq 6$, we can observe in 3D that $\log(y)$ is "close" to a bilinear function of $x$ and $k$. So, making a grid for these intervals, we can fit a model such that $$\log(y)=a+b x+c k+d k x$$ The resulting approximate model is then $$\log(y)=-1.17926 + 0.097592 x + 
 2.52133 k + 0.121287 x  k$$ from which $$x=\frac{-2.52133 k+ \log (y)+1.17926}{0.121287 k+0.0975917}$$ Applied to the examples used for illustration, this will give as estimates $3.39209$ and $8.42477$ which will lead to a very fast convergence to the solution.

You could also notice that, for any $k$, $F(x) > k +k\log(x)$ that is to say that an overestimate of the solution is $$\frac{1 }{e}y^{\frac{1}{k}}$$ which is probably too large to be used as a starting point of Newton mathod (as already pointed out by Ross Millikan) but at least it upper bounds the range for the search. This was obtained looking at the expansion of the function for large values of $x$ $$F(x)=k\left(1+ \log(x) \right)+\frac{k (k+1)}{2 x}-\frac{k^2 (2
   k+3)}{12 x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)$$

Comment: Unfortunately, I think Ross Millikan had a typo in his equation, so $F'(x)$ does not come out quite as simple. Instead, it looks like $F'(x)=\text{ln}(x+k)-\text{ln}(x)-\frac{k}{2x(x+k)}$. But the rest of your method should still  be usable. If it still converges within 3 or 4 iterations, this would be a great solution. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: *Just a quick note to myself*: For quicker evaluation, the functions can be written as $F(x)=(x+\frac{1}{2})\text{ln}\frac{x+k}{x}+k\,\text{ln}(x+k)-\text{ln}\,y\,$ and $F'(x)=\text{ln}\frac{x+k}{x}-\frac{k}{2x(x+k)}$

Comment: @MarkusA.. Thanks for pointing my mistake ! I shall edit now. Cheers :-)

Comment: *Another quick note to myself:* For [Halley's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method) we also need the second derivative: $F''(x)=\frac{k}{2x(x+k)}\left(\frac{1}{x+k}+\frac{1}{x}-2\right)$

Comment: Yes, for sure. As you noticed, it is quite simple. I shall add it to my answer. Thanks again for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This was too large to fit in the comment box, so I added it as an answer. It is a highly inefficient attempt to solve your equation using lengthy simplification, etc. There is probably a simpler way.

Start by turning it into a conglomerate of exponents:

$$(x+k)^{1/2}(x)^{-1/2}(x+k)^{x+k}x^{-x} = y$$

Simplify:

$$(x+k)^{x+k+1/2}(x)^{-x-1/2} = y$$

Apply natural logarithm:

$$\ln((x+k)^{x+k+1/2}(x)^{-x-1/2}) = \ln y$$

Rules for logarithms:

$$\ln((x+k)^{x+k+1/2})+\ln((x)^{-x-1/2}) = \ln y$$

Rules for logarithms:

$$(x+k+\frac12)\ln (x+k) +(-x-\frac12)\ln (x) = \ln y$$

Rules for logarithms:

> $$(x+k+\frac12)(\ln (x)+\ln (k))+(-x-\frac12)\ln (x) = \ln y$$

**Edit**: This is an entirely invalid operation, please disregard the rest.

Simplify:

$$(x+k+\frac12)\ln (k)+k\ln (x) = \ln y$$

Simplify some more:

$$x\ln (k)+k\ln (x) = \ln y-k\ln k-\frac 12\ln k$$

Rules for logarithms:

$$\ln (k^{x})+\ln (x^{k}) = \ln y-k\ln k-\frac 12\ln k$$

Rules for logarithms:

$$\ln (k^{x}x^{k})= \ln y-k\ln k-\frac 12\ln k$$

Exponentiate:

$$k^{x}x^{k}=e^{ln y-k\ln k-\frac 12\ln k}$$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Unfortunately, $ln(x+k)$ does not equal $(ln(x)+ln(k))$... :)

Comment: @Markus wow. haha well I guess you can basically disregard that then

Comment: (The downvote did not come from me... I do appreciate your attempt to help!)

Comment: Thanks! Don't worry about it.

Comment: This was a good effort I can't believe someone would downvote :( +1 to counter.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is $\frac{(x+k)^{(x+k+1/2)}}{x^{x+1/2}}=y\ \ $  No, you can't invert that easily.  I would take the log, getting $(x+k+\frac 12)\log (x+k) - (x+\frac 12) \log (x) = \log y$  You need to take some numeric approach.  For a starting value, we consider the logs on the left equal, as log is slowly changing.  Then it becomes $k\log(x_0)=\log y, x_0=y^{(1/k)}$  Looking at your plots, it seems this $x$ will be somewhat high.   I would cut $x_0$ in half enough times that the error changes sign so we have a bracket.  I would then use the secant method.  It will converge quickly because the curves don't have much curvature.  I didn't choose Newton's method because computing the formula for the derivative looks like a lot of trouble.

Comment: I think there might be a typo or two in your formula: I think it is $(x+k+\frac{1}{2})log(x+k)-(x+\frac{1}{2})log(x)$ (like @Tdonut wrote; without the $+\frac{1}{2}$ inside the log).

Comment: @MarkusA.:  you are correct.  Fixed.  Thanks.